# execute FNDLOAD command on unix server using Java

Tags: java, unix, ssh

I have a Java UI in windows. From that UI i want to **connect to unix server** and run `FNDLOAD` command.

I found a code [here](http://www.journaldev.com/246/java-program-to-run-shell-commands-on-ssh-enabled-system). But through this I am just able to run normal unix commands(like ls, cd, etc) and achieve output. But when I try to run `FNDLOAD` command, it gives me the following error

> bash: FNDLOAD: command not found

The `FNDLOAD utility` is installed on the server and also I'm able to attain the desired result when I connect to `putty` and run the command.

Is there any way I can run the command from Java?

**Edit 1:**
I'm using `jsch` add-on library to connect. Here is the code I'm using.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ShellExecuter {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "10.111.111.11";
        String user = "username";
        String password = "password";
        String FND_TOP = "/u01/oracle/fs1/appl/fnd/12.0.0";
        String command = "FNDLOAD user/pass O Y DOWNLOAD " + FND_TOP + "/patch/115/import/abc.lct "
                + "/home/applvis/JAVA/abc.ldt PROGRAM APPLICATION_SHORT_NAME=XX "
                + "CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_NAME=UPLOAD_TOOL";
        try {

            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected");

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                }
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            System.out.println("DONE");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Edit 2** 
Not only `FNDLOAD` command, I'm unable to get system variables also. Like if I give the command `$JAVA_TOP`, the code does not return anything. Nor does `cd $JAVA_TOP` works. :(

Anyone please help..

Comment: How are you launching a session on the server from Java?  Don't post a link, show us the actual code you are running. The issue is likely that the `PATH` on the server session is not set up correctly.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have posted my code. Please see the edit. I am using **JSCH** library. I think the `PATH` is correct as I'm able to run simple unix commands.

Comment: When you connect with ***ssh*** you get a minimal path.  You should probably specify the complete path to the `FNDLOAD` executable in your command line.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm sorry didn't properly understand what you are saying. Do you mean the before `FNDLoad` command I should move to a particular directory or add some path before `FNDLOAD` in the command?

Comment: @JimGarrison Can you please help me. I'm still struggling with this command. I tried moving to the FNDLOAD executable path, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. Here's the solution

FNDLOAD is an OS command line executable. In order to run it we must ensure our enviroment is set up correctly in the shell, before invoking `FNDLOAD`.

```
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("cd path/to/env/file; . ./envFileName.env;"+ command);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an application called MigrationLogiK (migrationlogik.com) which is specifically designed to address migration of custom EBS objects.  it has client and agent which is running on the server and allows to both execute FNDLOAD and download .ldt files back to the client workstation.  This way you don't need to hardcode any values. Pretty intuitive.